# KVM: network partially lost for the host, guests are fine

Tags: linux, networking, kvm

I got KVM working fine on a Linux system, for quite some weeks.

Then today something weird happened: suddenly the host (and the host only) lost some of its Internet access:

- it can still access the LAN (I can ssh to other machines)
- it can still access the guests (for example I can ssh from the host into a Linux guest)
- the forwarding still works (other physical machines on the LAN still have Internet access, yet their using the KVM host as the 'forwarder')

But I didn't touch any configuration file.  I was just browsing / using the guests.  I tried to *ifconfig down br0* and then *ifconfig up br0* and reset the route, but to not avail.

Does anyone have any idea as to what's going up?  It's my main workstation and it has 2 months of uptime: I don't like rebooting so I'd rather not have to do it (moreover it would just show that the machine ain't stable enough).

**EDIT**: I add here more details/answers hoping you guys can help me out a bit

Meanwhile I decided to do a shutdown and bring the machine back up and now everything is working fine again but still... I'd like to know if I could solve this the next time it happens without needing to shutdown the host.

> do your VMs us a 'public bridge' networking method? (ie: bridged to
>   local lan)

Yes I think so: I use *br0* and both the host and the VMs have IPs that are 10.0.0.x which is the same as other physical machines on my LAN

> is your host interface wired or wireless?

All wired, no WiFi at all at my home : )

> is your default gateway a commodity "router" such as you get from Verizon or Comcast?

It's a Zyxel that I setup myself (I didn't try rebooting it)

> if you reboot one of the VMs, does it receive a full network configuration, and is it still capable of reaching the internet, even when the host OS is not?

Yes.  That was the "crazy" part.  It's as if the host's IP had an issue but the "bridging" kept working fine: I did reboot both VMs and they did both get back network access.

I didn't *netstat -rn* because I had already rebooted the machine but I will next time there's an issue (and compare to a known ok *netstat -rn* that I now took).

Comment: Under Linux, gatewayed routes for which there is no non-gatewayed route to the router cannot exist. Bringing the link up and down manually using `ifconfig` or `ip link` will definitely kill the default route unless you have some daemon monitoring link status. Under *some* distributions, the canonical way is to use `ifup` and `ifdown`. Also, please [stop using `net-tools` (`netstat`, `ifconfig`, etc.), and use iproute2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93412/difference-between-ifconfig-and-ip-commands/93461#93461).

Comment: Did you ever find out what happened? I'm having a similar issue: http://serverfault.com/q/831471/73768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like maybe your host lost it's default route.

Some questions.

1. do your VMs us a 'public bridge' networking method?  (ie: bridged to local lan)
2. is your host interface wired or wireless?
3. is your default gateway a commodity "router" such as you get from Verizon or Comcast?
4. if you reboot one of the VMs, does it receive a full network configuration, and is it still capable of reaching the internet, even when the host OS is not?

My home router stops properly handing out DHCP every once in a while, and needs to be reset.  When this happens, anytime a lease expires, I can lose internet access until I reboot it.   Depending on how the VM networking is setup, your VMs may be receiving faux-DHCP information from QEMU, rather than sending out DHCP packets on the wire.

Check your routing table (`netstat -rn`) and make sure your default is a) there, and b) correct.

Wifi interfaces don't do bridging properly, if at all, but you mentioned that everything was working before, so I don't think that's going to be the culprit.

Comment: +1, thanks for helping me...  I answer your questions in an edit to my question because it's too long for a comment :)