# Difference between 'ifconfig' and 'ip' commands

Tags: linux, networking, ip, command

I read some articles/tutorials on 'ifconfig' command, most of them included a common statement -

> "ifconfig is deprecated by ip command"

and suggested to learn ip command. But none of them explained how 'ip' command is more powerful than 'ifconfig'.

What is the difference between both of them?

Comment: http://www.tty1.net/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison_en.html

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ifconfig` is from `net-tools`, which hasn't been able to fully keep up with the Linux network stack for a long time. It also still uses `ioctl` for network configuration, which is an ugly and less powerful way of interacting with the kernel.

A lot of changes in Linux networking code, and a lot of new features aren't accessible using `net-tools`: multipath routing, policy routing (see the RPDB). `route` allows you to do stupid things like adding multiple routes to the same destination, with the same metric.

Additionally:

- `ifconfig` doesn't report the proper hardware address for some devices.
- You can't configure `ipip`, `sit`, `gre`, `l2tp`, etc. in-kernel static tunnels.
- You can't create `tun` or `tap` devices.
- The way of adding multiple addresses to a given interface also has poor semantics.
- You also can't configure the Linux traffic control system using `net-tools` either.

See also [`ifconfig` sucks](http://inai.de/2008/02/19).

**EDIT**: Removed assertion about `net-tools` development ceasing that by now I forgot where I got for this post. `net-tools`' has been worked on since `iproute2` was released, though it's mostly bug fixing and minor enhancements and features, like internationalization.

Comment: NET-3 net-tools is not the only `ifconfig`.  There is a different one in GNU inetutils, for example.  And that is not all.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504084/5132

Answer (score 7):

`ifconfig` is a traditional command to display information about network interfaces and change some settings. In particular, it can bring interfaces up and down. It exists on most unix variants.

On Linux, the `ifconfig` command hasn't evolved in a long time. It's still perfectly fine for what it does. If you're using `ifconfig` for something, there's no reason to stop.

Linux also provides the `ip` command from the [iproute2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) tool suite. The `ip` command combines several classical commands and more, including `ifconfig`, `route` and `arp`. `ip` can do a lot more than `ifconfig`. On the other hand, `ip` isn't always present, especially on embedded systems (and never on unix variants other than Linux).

Parsing `ifconfig`'s output kinda sucks. Parsing `ip`'s output kinda sucks. No winner there.

Comment: I've always thought parsing `ip`'s output to be fairly simple, and certainly a heck of a lot simpler than `ifconfig`. I also love that in many cases the output of an `ip` command can be used as the input to another `ip` command with little or no modification (for example, every line of `ip route show` can be used as the arguments to `ip route add`).

Comment: @Patrick parsing the `ip route`, and `ip rule` output is pretty clear and pretty easy to parse.  But `ip link`, or `ip addr` is a pain.  I really wish someone would submit a patch or something to make the `ip addr` print out the exact statements, perhaps with a switch, that you would use setup the current config, like you get with `ip route show`.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add some bits to the answer by pilona. Around 2005 a new mechanism for controlling the network stack was introduced - [netlink sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink).

To configure the network interface `iproute2` makes use of that full-duplex netlink socket mechanism, while `ifconfig` relies on an `ioctl` system call. Here are 2 main papers on [motivation behind netlink](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356?page=0,1) and [usage of rtnetlink](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8498).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I have found the output of *ifconfig* easier to digest when compared with *ip-** commands, which IMO visually leave a bit to be desired. In my typical use I only need a subset of what is given, for example interface, status, ipaddress and in this regard *ifconfig* is easier to read.

ifconfig:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 297454  bytes 14872700 (14.1 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 297454  bytes 14872700 (14.1 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aabytes 596277 (582.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 9083  bytes 738309 (721.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aabytes 596277 (582.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 9083  bytes 738309 (721.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Compared with ip-address:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.10/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.20/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```